# Why does the punctured affine line deserve its name?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Let $k$ be a (commutative unitary) ring. The subobject $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,x^{-1}]\rightarrowtail \operatorname{Spec} k[x]=\mathbb A_k ^1$, where $k[x,x^{-1}]=k[x,y]/ \left\langle xy-1 \right\rangle$, is often called the *punctured affine line*. I've even seen $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,x^{-1}]$ denoted $\mathbb A_k^1\setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$.

Why does $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,x^{-1}]$ deserve this name and notation? Isn't this just the hyperbola $xy=1$ in the affine plane $\mathbb A_k^2$? On the other hand, if we look at $k[x,x^{-1}]$ as the localization of $k[x]$ at $ \left\{ x,x^2,\dots \right\}$, then $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]_x$ does look like we're looking at the points in which the polynomial $x\in k[x]$ is nonzero, which is "everything but zero"...

Comment: The zero set of $xy = 1$ in $\Bbb A^2$ is isomorphic as quasiprojective varieties to $\Bbb A^1- 0$, by projection to a coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details you seek can be found in Hartshorne. The claim is that the projection map from $X = V(xy-1) \subset \mathbb A^2$ to $Y = \mathbb A^1 - 0$ is an isomorphism of ringed spaces (I am thinking of $X$ and $Y$ as schemes). This means two things. The first thing is that the projection map is a homeomorphism, which I leave you to verify. $\mathbb A^1-0$ has the subspace topology from the Zariski topology from $\mathbb A^1$. The second is that the induced map $f^\#: \mathcal O_{Y} \to f_*\mathcal O_{X}$ of sheaves is an isomorphism (Hartshorne page 72-73). To verify that this map of sheaves is an isomorphism, one can check that the induced maps across stalks are all isomorphisms (page 63, Prop 1.1).

It is probably easier and better to first learn what a variety is, and to do this in the category of varieties first. The fact that we call the hyperbola the punctured affine line is a geometric idea (at least to me)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\mathbb A_k^1\setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$ is a Zariski open subset of $\mathbb A_k^1$ (being the complement of the zero set of $x$), and the projection $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy-1) \to \mathbb A_k^1\setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$  is an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces (the latter with structure sheaf being a restriction of the structure sheaf of $\mathbb{A}_k^1$).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm trying to understand why the Zariski topology (or a finer topology) is needed for this identification. What makes it not valid if we just take an arbitrary topology on $k$-$\mathsf Alg^\text{op}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The structure sheaf is defined on Zariski open subsets.

Comment: I mean one could define the category of affine $k$-scheme to be the opposite of $k$-algebras, and on this category, give any Grothendieck topology. I'm trying to understand what about the Zariski topology makes the projection $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy-1) \to \mathbb A_k^1\setminus \left\{ 0 \right\}$ an isomorphism of locally ringed spaces.  What would change in, say, the étale topology, etc.

Comment: Oh, I don't know :(

Comment: Okay :) Let me ask this - why is the projection an isomorphism of ringed spaces?

Comment: @Arrow The map given above comes with a map of structure sheaves. It is probably easiest to show that this map induces an isomorphism across stalks. The stalks for the structure sheaf of $\mathbb A^1 - 0$ just $k[t]_P$ for the prime ideals $P$ in $k[t]$.

Comment: @hwong557 I'm still not following. Does this all work for $k$ an arbitrary commutative ring? Could you elaborate in an answer?